# How to re-bind ListView on OnClick event of a button?

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

this seemed simple at first but I can't get it to work.

I have the following scenario:

```
        <asp:ListView ID="CommentsListView" runat="server">
            <LayoutTemplate>
                    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceholder" runat="server" />
            </LayoutTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <UC:Comment runat="server" CommentItem="<%# CurrentComment %>" />
                <br />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:ListView>
        <asp:TextBox ID="NewComment" runat="server" />
        <asp:ImageButton ImageUrl="/images/ball.png" runat="server"
                      OnClick="SubmitComment" />
```

Code:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         RenderListView();
    }

    protected void RenderListView()
    {
        CommentsListView.DataSource = //Get the data source objects
        CommentsListView.DataBind();
    }

    protected CommentObject CurrentComment
    {
        get { return (CommentObject)Page.GetDataItem(); }
    }

    protected void SubmitComment(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {   
        //code to submit comment

        RenderListView();
    }
```

basically, when I submit a comment, I want to see it in the ListView, but I don't. "MyControl" gets a null comment in the post-back, for all of the items (not just the new one).

Only after I refresh the page, I can see the new comment that I'v submitted. I can't however refresh the page every submit because this code is inside an UpdatePanel (the issue occurs without the UpdatePanel as well).

Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved it, if anyone else may encounter this -

The solution was to avoid "<%#" and instead use the ItemDataBound event:

```
 <asp:ListView ID="Comments" runat="server" 
OnItemDataBound="CommentsItemDataBound">
```

and the method itself:

```
protected void CommentsItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
    var commentItem = (Comment)(((ListViewDataItem)e.Item).DataItem);

    var commentControl = (Comment)e.Item.FindControl("CommentControl");
    commentControl.CommentItem = commentItem;
}
```

This way, the binding of each control works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find any specifics on this, but I have a hunch the user control in your ItemTemplate is causing the issue.  Can you remove it and see if it works?

Comment: Removing the problem doesn't solve it :) The problem is that the control gets a null `CurrentComment`. Outside of the UC everything works.

Answer (score 0):

I notice that you are calling RenderListView in both SubmitComment and PageLoad which I believe will cause it to fire twice when the button is clicked (with PageLoad firing first).  It looks like the code you posted is simplified.  Is it possible that there is something happening in the PageLoad which is sabotaging your SubmitComment steps?

Comment: hey Joseph, the Page_Load doesn't do anything else, I can't see how it sabotages the submitting. I should note that the submit is working, and the DataSource gets a valid list of non-null comments, always, the problem is just with the UC that doesn't seem to get the comment object (but gets a null instead).